# What is the word that shares meaning with "mausoleum" but sounds like 'chartomb' (/tʃaːtuːm/)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence:

> In 1984 the Long Island Lighting Company (LILCO) successfully
>   constructed a General Electric nuclear boiling water reactor about 60
>   miles east of New York City. However, before the power-on
>   testing would begin, an oil-financed, anti-nuclear, pro-solar power campaign had
>   swept through the small town of Shoreham, NY, where the plant was located, eventually
>   mobilizing the locals to successfully prevent LILCO from ever doing any
>   start-up tests at all, and ultimately winning the legal battle for the power station's
>   decommissioning.
>
> Today the site, complete and intact, is frozen in time as
>   a non-living museum of sorts, in its 25th year of neglect. This ***[chartomb]*** is as an empty a vessel as the promise it once held: to displace 3 million tons of carbon dioxide each year. Neighbored by gas and wind-turbines taking advantage of its grid infrastructure, it stands sentry over the area, now as CO2 contributor.

The word in the brackets shares a similar meaning with mausoleum or sarcophagus. It's expansive and sprawling, but barren and left to the elements.

IPA transcription: `/tʃaːtuːm/`

Comment: Was it "charred tomb"? Can you provide a link, please, with a time if it's a video.

Comment: This is yet another example of how [embedding video/audio in the question would be helpful.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/why-cant-we-add-video-or-even-audio-clips-to-posts)

Comment: It might be a false memory.

Comment: I did find a couple technical references to abandoned nuke sites that include the collocation "core tomb".

Comment: It's listed in the commonly available reference Thesaurus.com (under 'mausoleum').

Comment: @Lordology Thank you for the IPA edit. I was waiting a few day to come back here to see if my memory could retrieve the word on its own. It didn't but, I think it was probably your answer.

Comment: @Louis No problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for **catacomb**

> /kætəkuːm/ or /katəkəʊm/
>   **1.** *n.* (usually *catacombs*) An underground cemetery consisting of a subterranean gallery with recesses for tombs, as constructed by the ancient Romans.
>
> **1.1** *n.* An underground construction resembling or compared to catacombs.

Definition 1.1 is the correct definition in this context.

[*Lexico* Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/catacomb)

Comment: The pronunciation with /o/ is today more common than the one with /u/.

Comment: @tchrist I've never heard "kattakom"; always kattakoom in the UK, at least.

Comment: I'm never heard *catacoom* with /u/ either, only *catacome* with /o/. [Listen to these](https://youglish.com/pronounce/catacomb/english).

Comment: @tchrist  Wells in his Pronunciation Dictionary gives /ˈkætəku:m/ as the more common pronunciation in British English, /ˈkætəkəum/ as less common, and /ˈkæt̬əkoʊm/ as the only pronunciation in American English.

Comment: @petitrien Shouldn't those phonetic allophones be in brackets not slashes? Why are you using slashes for things that aren't phonemes in English? This actually makes a big difference here. /kom/ and /kum/ are a minimal pair, but what you wrote is two kinds of /o/ and so, being mere allophones, don''t count to make them different words in the ear of the listener.

Comment: @tchrist  I'm using Wells's notation that is different for BrE and AmE. "u:" is the GOOSE vowel, "əu" the GOAT vowel for BrE, "oʊ" the GOAT vowel for AmE.  The idea is that there are two ways to pronounce "catacomb" in BrE, one more common than the other, and only one in AmE.

Comment: Like @tchrist, I read this word with /o/ (North East USA).